# NoMethodError undefined method `user_path`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a navigation bar where I'm trying to show a profile page. However, I have been having some issues with it. The profile is created via a devise login and such, and so the user cannot create one once logged in. I only want the action to be able to see their profile, and edit their profile.  I keep having some problems with this, would anyone be able to take a quick look?

When I type in `rake routes` I wind up getting

```
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
user      GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
```

And so I was hoping in my `layouts` file to have:

```
= link_to 'Profile', users_path(@user_id)
```

If I have it at `users_path` I get an error stating `undefined method 'users_path'`. If I switch it to `user_path` I get a `no route matches`

My routes file looks like (this is the entire file)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :users, :only => [:show, :edit]
end
```

My controller I have:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Finally my views are set up at `"users/show"` ( I don't think that is where the issue is, but I felt like sharing that part as well)

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you should be linking with

```
= link_to 'Profile', user_path(@user.id)
```

You don't have anything defined for `@user_id`